# How to create an association with mapping different keys in two table and implying some logic on the column values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, associations

I have two tables

> **Content** (primary key : id , another_column : module_couch_id : string )
>
> **ContentDetails** (primary key : id, another_column : couch_id : string )

eg:

> **module_couch_id** => 'say_hello_to_the_world'
>
> **couch_id** => 'system.content.say_hello_to_the_world.en.us.192'

How do I define an association in the Content class so that I can do this

> Content.first.content_details & retrieve the data from the second

Comment: Define `content_details` method in `Content` Model like : `def content_details ContentDetails.map{|cd| return cd if cd.couch_id.include? self.module_couch_id} end` now when you run `Content.first.content_details` it will return the record you need.

Comment: Nice, but if I do a `Content.all` & then try to iterate over individual `ContentDetails` for each `content` this would result in a `n+1` query problem, I am trying to establish an association so that I can eager load it

Comment: We could do this in Content Model : `has_many :content_details, :foreign_key => :couch_id` but your `module_couch_id` & `couch_id` have different values and need to apply `include?` method to check if couch_id has substring module_couch_id.

Comment: yes thats what I think I am looking for on how to specify that `includes?` condition with a `has_many` block,

Comment: This should work : `has_many :content_details, -> (object) { where("couch_id like ?", "%#{object.module_couch_id}%") }, :foreign_key => 'couch_id'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a column `content_id` of type `integer` to `ContentDetails` table. This is the column that ties both `Content` and `ContentDetails`.

Then by defining the following in your models as follows:

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :content_details
end

class ContentDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :content
end
```

You should be able to:

`Content.first.content_details`

Comment: Yes, that I know,but I don't have write access on the table so the association needs to reside on the module_couch_id & the couch_id field, hence the question on how to write an association withhout content_id field but the couch_id fields in both tables

Answer (score 0):

This approach should work :

```
has_many :content_details, -> (object) { where("couch_id like ?", "%#{object.module_couch_id}%") }, :foreign_key => 'couch_id'
```